# Access list elements with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, html-lists, devextreme

I have a list with 2 images per line, after filling the list with my datasource, I need to set one of the images with "visible = false" depending on the user's choice, I am not able to access the list elements to set one of the images = false

list html

```
            <div data-bind="dxList: {items: listItems, dataSource: AdataSource, pullRefreshEnabled: true }" id="lxDados">
            <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } " id="dxtemp">

                <div class="us-linha-img">
                    <span class="dx-icon-map icon us-itens-linha"></span>
                    <span class="us-itens-linha" data-bind="text: evento"></span>
                </div>

                <img id="imcodb" data-bind="attr: { src: $data.codbar, alt: $data.codbar }" />
                <br />
                <img id="imcodbqr" data-bind="attr: { src: $data.codbarqr, alt: $data.codbar }" />

            </div>
        </div>
```

js file
In this function, after loading the list with my datasource, I need to scroll through the list and set one of the "img" to visible = true or false.

```
function trocarCodBar(m) {
AdataSource = loadDataSource();
viewModel.AdataSource(AdataSource);
//done...
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.listItems().length; i++) {
    if(m=='bar')
    //set <img imcodb or imcodbqr visible false or true.
}}
```

view

```
var viewModel = {
bloadpanel: ko.observable(false),
AdataSource: null,
listItems: ko.observableArray(),
trocarCodBarBar: function () {
    trocarCodBar("bar");
},
trocarCodBarQR: function () {
    trocarCodBar("qrc");
},
viewShown: function () {
    //alterar valores na inicialização
},
title: ko.observable("Pedido: " + params.id)};
viewModel.AdataSource = AdataSource;
return viewModel;
```

Comment: you may want to add devExtreme to your tags. (I'm guessing that is what dxlist is?)

Comment: Yes, I'm using DevExtreme, dxList is the DevExtreme List.

Comment: ...you may want to add it to your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a good practice to use html elements inside a knockout view model. Just use [ko.observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to manage a dynamic rendering.

First of all, create the observables fields within your data set like below:

```
vm.dataSource = ko.observableArray([
    { text: "a", firstImageVisible: ko.observable(true), secondImageVisible: ko.observable(false) },
    { text: "b", firstImageVisible: ko.observable(true), secondImageVisible: ko.observable(false) },
    { text: "c", firstImageVisible: ko.observable(true), secondImageVisible: ko.observable(false) }
]);
```

In your case there are two ways to change image visibility.

The first one is the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: '...' }, visible: firstImageVisible "/>
<img data-bind="attr: { src: '...' }, visible: secondImageVisible "/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ofbugahL/

The second way is the [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding:

```
<!-- ko if: firstImageVisible -->
<img data-bind="attr: { src: '...' } "/>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: secondImageVisible -->
<img data-bind="attr: { src: '...' } "/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0nkju2Lz/

Next, if you want to show the first image, just set the `firstImageVisible` field to `true` and the `secondImageVisible` field to `false`. Knockout automatically updates your list.